# How to make a debian live usb efi?

Tags: usb, debian, efi

I'm struggling to create a Debian 7 netinstall live usb key which can boot with efi.

I can't find documentation or tutorials about this manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian 7 is efi ready ootb.
The mistake I made is that my usb key was formatted in NTFS rather than FAT32.